# how to assign NA to non-existent html_node using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I have several hundred HTML files to parse using `rvest`. However, some HTML file might miss certain nodes, how do I write an if statement to assign `NA`s when the node is missing?

Right now, I got this error message

> 'Error in UseMethod("xml_find_first") :  no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"

I wrote the following function, but it doesn't work.

```
extractor<-function(file,htmlnode){

if(is.na(html_node(file,htmlnode))){
   a<-c('non-exist')

}else{

   a<-read_html(file)%>%
    html_node(htmlnode)%>%
    html_text()%>%
    clean_up()
   }

 return(a)
 }
```

Comment: instead of `if (is.na(...)`, the error suggests that you might try checking `if (inherits(x, 'xml_missing'))`

Comment: `html_nodes()` should return NA if the node is not found.